# How to deselect select input with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I use [this link](https://www.cssscript.com/demo/filterable-checkable-multi-select/) for select option in my HTML pages(select2 in below).

[image]

My cod exist in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/magi2109/x9q5aLy6/) too.
I want deselect all with JQuery. I use so many code but not working for this option.

```
var elements = document.getElementById("field2").selectedOptions;

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].selected = false;
    }
```

or

```
document.getElementById("field2").value = "";
```

or

```
$('#field2').find($('option')).attr('selected',false)
```

Comment: `selected` is a flag attribute - as such, you need to remove it, not set it to false.  Setting the value to `""` should work but you may need to refresh / `.trigger("change")` after changing the value - depending the plugin you use.

Comment: question is not clear to me, you can already select all by clicking on the `all` option then deselect all again by clicking on the same option. So what exactly is the problem? they all appear selected on page refresh?

Comment: `$("#field2").val("")` updates/clears your wrapped-select just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/bhu85vkz/ as does your example `document.getElementById("field2").value = "";`  https://jsfiddle.net/bhu85vkz/1/

Comment: @freedomn-m can you give me code on JSFiddle?

Comment: @ChrisG I want use kquery not use `all`

Comment: @freedomn-m `jsfiddle.net/bhu85vkz` its work and clear search box but not clear option selected. can you fix that?

Comment: You mean the opposite?  It clears the selection, but leaves the filter/search

Comment: Found what you mean - `.val("")` removes the tags, but doesn't update the drop down - you need to call  `.loadOptions()` to refresh the dropdown and `.next()[0].refresh()` to update the select when changing the dropdown-wrapper (so not needed in your case, just adding).

Comment: I *strongly* suggest you use a better dropdown replacement, such as [tag:select2] which has substantially more features and better documentation (ie, *some* documentation).  But it may not fit your use-case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248261/discussion-between-henrry-and-freedomn-m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the specific plugin you're using, you can clear the selection with

```
$("#id").val("");
```

and you can reset the wrapper using

```
$("#id")[0].loadOptions()
```

(`[0]` as it's a js function added by the wrapper)

Updated snippet:

```js
$("#clearBtn").click(() => {
  $("#field2").val("");
  $("#field2")[0].loadOptions();
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 20em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.cssscript.com/demo/filterable-checkable-multi-select/multiselect-dropdown.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col ">
      <label>Select 2</label>
      <select name="field2" id="field2" multiple multiselect-search="true" multiselect-select-all="true" multiselect-max-items="3" onchange="console.log(this.selectedOptions)">
        <option>Abarth</option>
        <option>Alfa Romeo</option>
        <option>Aston Martin</option>
        <option>Audi</option>
        <option>Bentley</option>
        <option>BMW</option>
        <option>Bugatti</option>
        <option>Cadillac</option>
        <option>Chevrolet</option>
        <option>Chrysler</option>
        <option>Citroën</option>
        <option>Dacia</option>
        <option>Daewoo</option>
        <option>Daihatsu</option>
        <option>Dodge</option>
        <option>Donkervoort</option>
        <option>DS</option>
        <option>Mazda</option>
        <option>McLaren</option>
        <option>Mercedes-Benz</option>
        <option>Skoda</option>
        <option>Smart</option>
        <option>SsangYong</option>
        <option>Subaru</option>
        <option>Suzuki</option>
        <option>Tesla</option>
        <option>Toyota</option>
        <option>Volkswagen</option>
        <option>Volvo</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<hr />
<button id='clearBtn'>clear</button>
```